# Get geotiff Transform from point correspondences

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I am trying to find a way to get the Geo Transformation (NW corner position, pixel size and rotation) for a given tiff image. I have a tiff which I know is using some coordinate reference system (an UTM projection using the WGS84 reference ellipsoid).

I would like to make it a geotiff using a software by associating, for example, point correspondences between the tiff image and a reference map. I would love to use something like Maptiler, but without the 10k*10k limitation on the image resolution.

For now, the solution I can think of is to downscale the input tiff, use Maptiler to get the GeoTransform, then use GDal to make this tiff a Geotiff by upscaling the pixelSizes by the inverse coefficient.

Are there any free alternatives to generate a geotiff by using correspondences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process of finding the geotransform or building a geotiff from a given raaster image is known as **Geo-Referencing**. Instead of using Maptiler, I can use **QGis** with the **GeoReferencer plugin**, which, as it is well presented [netpalantir](http://netpalantir.it/news/index/how-to-georeference-an-image) and in [digital-geography](http://www.digital-geography.com/qgis-tutorial-i-how-to-georeference-a-map/#.Ve1YmbOYpnw), can also be used with a nice GUI.